# Observable inside Ngfor

Tags: angular, firebase

I am learning programming...

I am making some kind of forum using angularfire2 (firebase) I have 2 services, one that manages all user profile data and the other the messages. With an *ngfor I display all the messages (calling a function of the service in the component). The message interface has the uid of the user that submitted the message. With this uid I want to get the user profile picture for example to be displayed in the message.

The problem is that when I call the function I get an Observable inside an observable and my app starts a bucle. What do I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

admin.requests.component.html .

```
    <div *ngFor="let request of requests" class="card shadow">



    ..img  ... src="{{getUserProfilePicture(request.clientId)}}" ... ">
```

getUserProfilePicture(uid) returns the value of the imgURL of the DOC where uid = clientId

Comment: Are you saying `requests` is an array of observables? Or is it that `getUserProfilePicture` returns an observable?

Comment: I mean getUserProfilePicture returns an observable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe):

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the
>   latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async
>   pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component
>   gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid
>   potential memory leaks.

So, if your observable returns a string with your image src, your refactored code might look like:

```html
    ..img  ... src="{{getUserProfilePicture(request.clientId) | async}}" ... ">
```

I created a [working example of the async pipe](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2qpsc9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.html) in an `ngFor` loop for reference.

Some potential things to watch out for with the async pipe: every time you use that same observable, it will subscribe to the observable again unless you capture the value using the `as` syntax. What this means is: if you have an async pipe that calls a web service, for example, it will be called multiple times if you do something like this:

```html
<!-- Async pipe subscribes once... -->
<img src="{{someHttpCall(request.clientId) | async}}"/>
<!-- Async pipe subscribes again... -->
<p>Img loaded from: {{someHttpCall(request.clientId) | async}}</p>
```

If you wanted to refactor the above to us the `as` syntax to capture the output and avoid multiple server calls, it would look like this:

```html
<!-- Capture our observable to prevent subsequent subscriptions. 
     Async pipe only subscribes once. -->
<ng-container *ngIf="someHttpCall(request.clientId) | async as imgSrc">
   <img src="{{ imgSrc }}"/>
   <!-- Also note we don't need the async pipe because it already subscribed 
        to the observable for us and we captured the value in our template -->
   <p>Img loaded from: {{ imgSrc }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

Anyway, that's a pitfall that a lot of new Angular developers fall into so I figured I wouldn't introduce the `async` pipe without at least a little word of caution.